# Inaccessible Partition During OS Reinstallation

Tags: partitioning, reinstall

My Acer laptop crashed and won't go beyond the splash screen. 
The only way I see to this problem is with a clean reinstallation.
When I try to delete the primary partition I  get:

```
Error:0x8007045d

- Diagnose and Startup Repair option fail.
```

Command Prompt:

```
X:\Sources>diskpart
```

After selecting primary disk '0' and followed by clean option
I get this error:

```
DiskPart has encountered an error: "The request could not be performed
because of an I/O device error.
See the System Event Log for more information."
```

So my disk is inaccessible, but it does exist.
What's my next option?

Comment: The drive is probably defective.

Comment: I would concur with @GabrielaGarcia using just the information given, this certainly appears to be a bad hard drive.

Comment: That is what I thought. Thanks for the input  @GabrielaGarcia . I'll take it from here!

Comment: Thanks for corroborating, @acejavelin. I'll see if I can install a new HDD myself. Live and learn.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information given, your problem is most likely that your HDD has failed or is in the process of failing.

The correct solution is to get another HDD and use it instead.

Comment: Based on the previous advice given including yours, a new HDD is the only option available. At least I have a new fresh starting point.